# Find the area of the triangle enclosed by the given equations: $y=-\frac12x-2, y=\frac13 x-2, $ and $ y=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Find the area of the triangle enclosed by the given equations:

> $y=-\frac12 x-2$
>    $y=\frac13 x-2$
>   $y=0$

Comment: Try finding the points of intersection of the lines.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection points are $(-4,0)$, $(6,0)$ and $(0,-2)$. The distance between the points on the line $y=0$ is $10$; the distance from $(0,-2)$ to the line $y=0$ is $2$.

[image]

Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this is to find all the three points of intersection by solving two equations at a time simultaneously and then calculating the area of the triangle enclosed by the three points. Since y=0 is an equation, so you can put the value of y in the other two equations to easily get the value of x and get two points. To get the third point, solve the first two equations.

If the three points are, $$ (x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3) $$ , then area of the triangle enclosed is given by:
$$ 
  \frac {1} {2} \begin{vmatrix}
    x_1 & y_1 & 1\\
    x_2 & y_2 & 1\\
    x_3 & y_3 & 1
  \end{vmatrix} 
$$

Comment: This should help: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5coqqg5x9z

Comment: I think you can solve it more simply by using $Area = \frac12 * Base * Height$

Comment: Yeah, that always depends. After getting the points, if you can easily get to know the height, then you should go for it. Otherwise, using determinant is the general way.

Comment: For this one the simpler formula holds (check the link).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Here, two of the points are collinear and lie on the x-axis, so you know the height. I was just trying to explain the general method.

Comment: I was taught that it should be: $\frac 12  *$\begin{vmatrix}
    x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_1\\
    y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_1
   \end{vmatrix}

Comment: Is this right as the coordinates are not collinear?

Comment: Yes, thats right too. It's called Steps Rule, and can be used for any regular polygon.

Comment: What is the name of the one you used? I have never heard about it.

Comment: I don't know the name honestly :P

Comment: The area is *half the absolute value* of that determinant.

Comment: @egreg if that was meant for me then I did multiply by $\frac12$ but could not bring it to a proper form.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan No, it was meant for the answer owner (now it has been edited in).

Comment: You are no human if you don't make mistakes :P